# Dhtmlx: data input saved in different format than showed in input

Tags: javascript, sql, calendar, dhtmlx

I bineded a form to one grid and tried to make a calendar input by using this:

> { type: "calendar",  dateFormat: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s", name:"creationdate", label:"",  labelWidth:250, labelAlign:"left", readonly: false, enableTime: true, calendarPosition: "under", labelLeft:825, labelTop:75, inputWidth:297, inputLeft:303, inputTop:116  }

After i select the date, it is shown in this format **2013-04-15 07:35:00** but after i hit saved it's shown in this format to my grid: **Mon Apr 15 2013 07:35:00 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time)**. How can i make it to show in the same format as in my calendar input?

The problem is that this format it's not saved in my DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set the date format to my grid:

> grid.setDateFormat("%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s");